# jQuery UI dialog - add handler for custom button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I added a custom button to my jQuery UI dialog titlebar, as follows:

```
$('#dialog').html(html);
$('#dialog').dialog({
    modal: true,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").append("<a href=\"#variants\" id=\"variants-button\"><img src=\"admin-images/variants-button.png\" alt=\"Variants\" /></a>");
    }
});
```

Now I need to add a 'click' handler to this button, but I am struggling with this.

```
$('#variants-button').click(function(){
    $('#information').hide();
    $('#variants').show();
    return false;
});
```

This doesn't do anything. I have also tried putting the click handler in a 'delegate' but that doesn't work either. Any ideas?

EDIT: zysoft has provided the correct solution, but I need this to work with multiple dialogs on the page. It does not seem to work as expected with multiple dialogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button is added in runtime when dialog opens. It seems to happen after you assign click handler. Try this:

```
$('#variants-button').live('click', function(){
    $('#information').hide();
    $('#variants').show();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Cheers, that has worked. I was considering using 'live' but then I read somewhere that it should not be used any more?

Comment: `live` has been deprecated.  Use `delegate` for pre-1.7 jQuery and `on` for 1.7+ jQuery.

Comment: Cheers David, can you check my edit in the original post. Thanks.

Comment: Change item id to a class and then update selector to look like this: `$('.dialog-button').on('click', function() { ....});`

Then it will react on all buttons that have `dialog-button` class

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just create the click handler after you append the new button?

```
$('#dialog').html(html);
$('#dialog').dialog({
    modal: true,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").append("<a href=\"#variants\" id=\"variants-button\"><img src=\"admin-images/variants-button.png\" alt=\"Variants\" /></a>");
        $('#variants-button').click(function(){
            $('#information').hide();
            $('#variants').show();
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

If you add the event handler after you add the element to the DOM, you should be OK.

**UPDATE**
Based on your update, if you wanted to do something like this to multiple dialog title buttons, a delegate may be better (since you'll avoid having to do this for every dialog).

You could apply a class to your button (e.g. `variant-class`) that acts as a marker class that you'll use as a selector to your `on` handler:

```
$('.variant-class').on('click', function() {
  $('#information').hide();
  $('#variants').show();
  return false;
});
```

I hope this helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Do you execute after you append the the HTML? If not, try using jQuery live insteed.

```
$('#variants-button').click(function(){
    $('#information').hide();
    $('#variants').show();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `live` has been deprecated.  Use `delegate` for pre-1.7 jQuery and `on` for 1.7+ jQuery.